# grails adding a domain object to another domain without the domains having a relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multiple-domains

Good day. I'm new to grails and groovy and what I'm trying to do is add a domain object (in my case an album object) to a different domain (cart). When the user clicks on the 'add to cart' link when viewing albums, the 'buy' action of the HomeController is supposed to create a duplicate of the album and put it into the Cart domain, except I have no idea how to do it. Here's what I got.

```
class HomeController{
   def index(){ 
      //displays a list of albums and a 'add to cart' link at each album in the list
   }

   def buy(){
      //Here's where the code should go.
      redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to give more thought into your domainClasses before attempting the views/controllers:

You have a domain object (in my case an album object) to a different domain (cart)

Domain classes:

```
class User {
    String name
    static hasMany = [orders:Orders]
}

Class Album {
    String name
}

class Order {
    User user
    Album album
}
```

View: A controller action to show this:

```
<!-- by defining user.id and album.id when grails receives the .id it binds that id to the actual object so --!>
<!-- User user = params.user  // is the user object bound to user.id --!>
<g:form action="save" controller="myController">
    <g:hidden name="user.id" value="1"/>
    <g:select name="album.id" from="${mypackage.Album.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"/>
    <g:submitButton name="save">
</g:form>
```

Controller to receive that save action - the saving functionality should really be taken over to a transactional service = This is just to show you very basically:

```
package mypackage

class MyController {

    def save() { 

        Order order= new Order(params)
        order.save()

        // 
        //User user=User.get(params.user.id) 
        User user=params.user

        user.addToOrders(order)
        user.save()

        render "album added to order class and then order added to users class"
    }
}
```